# Bundling not working in MVC 5 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I don't know what's going on but I can't get Bundles to work at all.

In my RegisterBundles, I have

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{                       
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

And in my view, I have

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

Now, I know that in my web.config I am running with

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

and I've ready elsewhere that bundling can't be run with debug mode false, but 'BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;' should deal with that. But it's not loading the bundle at all, and if I put breakpoints in the RegisterBundles method it never hits them. The markup it generates is just

```
 <script src="/bundles/jquery"></script>
```

Now I know that the location is correct because if I simply manually put in

```
 <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
```

It all works fine. How do I get the bundling to fire?

Comment: In your Global.asax.cs, do you call `RegisterBundles()`?

Comment: try a wildcard, *, instead of version, see if that helps

Comment: That was it, mason! I hadn't added it to my global.asax.cs file! It all works now, it seems!